# Can I incorporate a link in a message box in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a link in my javascript messagebox function.  Is there a way to do that?

```
TodayDate = new Date();
if (sender._selectedDate < new Date(TodayDate.getYear(), TodayDate.getMonth()-1, 1)) 
{
alert("Only current and previous months active.\n\nPlease visit\n
Agency ...HOMEPAGE...\nfor Archive Commissions");
sender._selectedDate = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not supported. You need to create your own modal dialog using an absolutely-positioned DIV.

Comment: Or better yet a fixed position div. Besides: native dialogs are sooo ugly.

Answer (score 3):

A javascript framework, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), makes this a relatively easy task.

There are several jQuery plugins that allow you to create a div with your dialog content on the page, and that div becomes a JavaScript dialog when the show dialog event fires. They can be easily styled, and also most include pre and post event callback functionality