# link in alert boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question.  I have the following code:

```
alert("Are you sure you want to add: \n" + redirURL + "?");
```

the variable redirURL is an actual working url.  I would like it to be 'clickable'

thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I incorporate a link in a message box in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966848/can-i-incorporate-a-link-in-a-message-box-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only display text in the alert function. If you want to put an url, you can do it by using jquery's dialog function. Here are some code examples: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: is it possible to do it without query? I am more interested in pure alert

Comment: This is **not** a jQuery dialog — it's a jQueryUI dialog.

Answer (score 43):

use `window.confirm` instead of `alert`

```
if (window.confirm('If you click "ok" you would be redirected . Cancel will load this website ')) 
{
window.location.href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html';
};
```

Comment: How do you get that to open to a new window?

Answer (score 5):

**If you want to open the Link on alert and that too in new window, Use the code below:**

```
if (window.confirm('Ok to Confirm, Cancel to Stay here'))
   {
   window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
   };
```

> *Note that most browsers will treat these links as popup.*

**There is an alternative too, Both works same, find it below:**

```
//write this above first
let a=document.createElement('a');
a.target='_blank';
a.href='https://www.google.com';

//then use this code for alert
if (window.confirm('Ok to Confirm, Cancel to Stay here'))
{
a.click();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible to put clickable links in alert windows.
The closest thing you could do is using a modal window, like this: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 2):

You can't put clickable URLs in a standard `alert()` box.  Instead you could use a "lightbox", which is an HTML popup - there are any number of them available, and you should choose one that fits well with the rest of your site/applicaiton.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in any "standard" web browser that I'm aware of.

I'd suggest using a more robust approach like [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with window.alert that you are using. Instead you can try using dialog plugins like modal plugin from [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) or [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Your hyperlink is an html where as alert box is non html component of the browser generated by browser's javascript.

> The alert dialog should be used for messages which do not require any response on the part of the user, other than the acknowledgement of the message.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert)

Answer (score 0):

This is a method with Jquery's Dialog

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <style></style>
  </head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='template/js/jquery.textarea-expander.js'></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <---- VENTAÑAS DE PARAMETERES---->
$(document).ready(function() { 
var regex,v,l,c,b,i,contapara=3;




$( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {
                "Link": function() {
                   location.href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973240/link-in-alert-boxes-javascript";
    return false;  },
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: {}
        });


                $( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog( "open" );


                    });
</script>
  <body>

<div id="wnd_Addparam" title="Information" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```