# How to display js alert popup box with a particular word being a link to click on?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, alert

I'm unable to create a alert box with having a link that you can click on to open up the link. This message should popup as a alert with the word "System Form" being a url link to click on it and how to make "System Form" underlined url in a alert message?:

Example Alert message: "Please complete System Form and get a signature approval before attaching the form."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I incorporate a link in a message box in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966848/can-i-incorporate-a-link-in-a-message-box-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link in Javascript alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733410/link-in-javascript-alert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not modify the system alert message, but you can use jQuery to make your own alerts, that can contain icons and hyperlinks. Try below snippet, please modify css as per your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#btnTest').click(function(){
ShowCustomDialog();
});
                  });


   function ShowCustomDialog()
   {
                
   ShowDialogBox('Warning','<a href="https://tipstricksandhacking.blogspot.com"> Record</a> updated successfully.','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
   }

            function ShowDialogBox(title, content, btn1text, btn2text, functionText, parameterList) {
                var btn1css;
                var btn2css;

                if (btn1text == '') {
                    btn1css = "hidecss";
                } else {
                    btn1css = "showcss";
                }

                if (btn2text == '') {
                    btn2css = "hidecss";
                } else {
                    btn2css = "showcss";
                }
                $("#lblMessage").html(content);

                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    title: title,
                    modal: true,
                    width: '400px',
                    height: 'auto',
                    bgiframe: false,
                    hide: { effect: 'scale', duration: 400 },

                    buttons: [
                                    {
                                        text: btn1text,
                                        "class": btn1css,
                                        click: function () {
                                                                                    
                                            $("#dialog").dialog('close');

                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: btn2text,
                                        "class": btn2css,
                                        click: function () {
                                            $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                });
            }
```

```css
  .showcss{ display:block;}
  .hidecss{ display:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="button" id ="btnTest" value="Test"/>
        <div id="dialog" title="Alert message" style="display: none">
            <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
                <p>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0"></span>
                    <label id="lblMessage">
                    </label>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a better solution to the problem than my own.

Comment: Thanks @DonnyBridgen :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to insert a hyperlink in a javascript alert. It would be a better idea to use a confirm dialog like this:

```js
   var goToSystemForm = confirm('Please complete System Form and get a signature approval before attaching the form. Would you like to be directed there now?');

if (goToSystemForm){
    window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
else{
    //do something else or nothing?
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. You cannot redirect someone who has connected over HTTPS. Therefore it will not work on this site or jsfiddle. You can incorporate this solution on your page or try another.